# Locating records while in transaction

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have revised a Quote, CRM2011 creates a new Quote, copies the products and updates the revision. I have a custom entity related to this Quote. I need the quotedetailid from the QuoteDetails to update this related entity.

In the post-create of the Quote I check the ParentContext for the message "Revise". Once found, I retrieve the related entities. I loop through these entities trying to find the QuoteDetail. No QuoteDetail is found.

After the revising is done the QuoteDetails become available.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the plugin is registered as a "Post-Operation" on the "quote" entity in "child pipeline" in "asynchronous execution mode".